# Excel cell value displayed incorrectly with Excel.Interop and C#

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am dynamically adding a 13 digit value to an Excel cell via Excel.Interop and C#. However, the value is displayed as something in the lines of `7,21119E+12` instead of `7211192800080`. If you click on the cell, then the display is correct.

```
//_ReportData is a DataTable with a single item
for (int i = 0; i < _ReportData[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < _ReportData[0].Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        excelCellRange_data = ((Worksheet)excelWorksheet_data).Cells;
        var cellValueRange = ((Range)excelCellRange_data)[i, j + 1];
        if (i == 0)
            ((Range)cellValueRange).Value2 = _ReportData[0].Columns[j].ToString(); //This is where the columns are set
        else
            ((Range)cellValueRange).Value2 = _ReportData[0].Rows[i][j].ToString(); //This is where the values are set
    }
}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

That's a Excel-"problem". If you type the number directly in a cell an press enter, the same issue will appear. If you first format the cell as number, it will be shown right.

```
((Range)cellValueRange).NumberFormat = "0";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the issue. The value is passed in as a string from the database, so I did a `long.tryparse()` to ensure I am working with a number, but still not satisfied.

Comment: Well, I tried it and it works correct with numbers up to 15 digits (999999999999999). If the number is bigger, Excel can't handle it correctly. E.g. a number with 17 digits 99999999999999999 will be shown as 99999999999999900... Don't know why... Anyway, if you don't want Excel to calculate with this numbers, you can try it with a leading apostroph `((Range)cellValueRange).Value2 = "'" + _ReportData[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();`

Comment: Don't know what I did differently, but it seemed to have sorted itself out. I queried actual production data and there was no issue as opposed to the dev environment data...strange though

Answer (score 1):

You should insert value without `ToString()` method.
Excel should apply format automatically from inserted value type.

Comment: The issue still persists, even if I remove the ToString() method